# LUIS Docker Image not running on Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

So I have Windows 2016 Server and I followed the Docker Install Documentation to download Docker-EE. After which moved ahead to pull the Microsoft LUIS Docker Image. When I start that I get the following Error: **image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform**

I understand that one has to change the Daemon to make that image work. But **DockerCli.exe** isnt present in the Docker Program Folder to call the **--SwitchDaemon** function. Moreover, I can't Download **Docker Desktop** to do that same.

I know that Microsoft LUIS Doesnt have Windows version as per the **Tag List**

Could somebody please explain how I can achieve this? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please consider posting relevant info from your link (Docker image) in the question.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work (maybe because I can only run Win Server 2016 in a VM), but you can try [these directions](https://www.docker.com/blog/preview-linux-containers-on-windows/)